# Dynamically End Flutter ListView

Tags: android, flutter, listview

I have a ListView widget (using `ListView.builder(...)`) that displays a long list of paginated query results that are lazily fetched from a remote db. Because the results are paginated, I don't know how many results there are until the user has scrolled through them all.

How do I set the itemCount (or otherwise fix the length) of a dynamic ListView after the ListView has been constructed? I could replace the ListView with a new one with a set itemCount once the itemCount is known, but that sounds really sloppy and potentially expensive (I assume flutter isn't smart enough to reuse the old ListView's children?).

Comment: Can u use a Column?

Comment: I'd have to rebuild all the ListView's logic on top of the column widget, at that point just rebuilding the parent widget with itemCount set is preferrable.

Comment: *"I could replace the ListView with a new one with a set itemCount once the itemCount is known, but that sounds really sloppy and potentially expensive"* - it is perfectly ok to go with that approach

Comment: If you had your list = [], and set the itemCount to list.length it should technically update and build accordingly as the list updates; does that not work?

Answer (score 0):

I decided that there was a fundamental issue with my approach:
a user could scroll arbitrarily far (past the limit of the list) because the actual length of the list is not known until the stream is done. So I revised my approach (in line with Aknahseh_tg's suggestion) such that the user see's a fixed list the length of the currently loaded elements with a final placeholder element that says "loading" at the end if the stream has not emitted a 'Done' event yet.